# Writing a function with arguments that indicate what function to apply

Tags: r

Is there a way to write a function in which one of the arguments indicates what function to apply?

For example, if I have a function:

```
mf = function(data, option, level)
```

where I want option to tell whether to calculate the `mean`, `median` or `sd` of a data set?

Comment: I think you're looking for `?switch`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, one option is to just pass a function to `option`. E.g.

```
mf <- function(data, option) {
    option <- match.fun(option)
    option(data)
}

set.seed(42)
dat <- rnorm(10)
mf(dat, option = mean)
```

Which gives:

```
> set.seed(42)
> dat <- rnorm(10)
> mean(dat)
[1] 0.5472968
> mf(dat, option = mean)
[1] 0.5472968
> sd(dat)
[1] 0.8354488
> mf(dat, option = sd)
[1] 0.8354488
```

`match.fun()` is the standard R way of matching to an available function. In the example I pass the function itself, but `match.fun()` allows other ways of referring to a function, for example as a character string:

```
> mf(dat, option = "mean")
[1] 0.5472968
```

`match.fun()` returns a function that can be used as any other function, hence `option()` is a function that is essentially the same as the function passed to the `option` argument or is the function named in the `option` argument.

It isn't clear how the `level` argument was supposed to be used to I have ignored that above.

I should probably add that if you want to pass in any arguments to the applied function then you'll want to use `...` in the function definition, e.g.:

```
mf <- function(data, option, ...) {
    option <- match.fun(option)
    option(data, ...)
}
```

Hence we can do things like this

```
set.seed(42)
dat2 <- rnorm(10)
dat2[4] <- NA
mean(dat2)
mean(dat2, na.rm = TRUE)
mf(dat2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

the last three lines giving

```
> mean(dat2)
[1] NA
> mean(dat2, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0.5377895
> mf(dat2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0.5377895
```

Comment: Doesn't work when passed a data.frame with `median` and sd.data.frame and mean.data.frame both generate warnings.

Comment: If the OP cares to explain what a "data set" then I'll give a more general approach. The OP asks for methods to apply an unknown function at function definition time; that is what I show. I agree you need to be a little more creative if "data set" means a data frame along the lines you propose.

Answer (score 4):

There is a bit of a problem in that "data set" in R usually means a dataframe and there is no median.data.frame so you need to use both lapply and do.call:

```
  df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))
 mf = function(data, option="mean") {lapply( data, 
                                       function(col) do.call(option, list(col))) }
 mf(df)
#-------------
$x
[1] 0.01646814

$y
[1] 0.5388518
```

You did not indicate what "level" was supposed to do, so I left it out of the equation,

```
> mf(df, sd)
$x
[1] 1.169847

$y
[1] 0.8907117
```

Comment: To clarify, "level" refers to different factor levels for a variable.